# How to fetch custom object's record details using case?

Tags: apex, visualforce, pageblocktable

I'm trying to fetch the custom objects record details and display on the VF page with below code.

In my case, I have case lookup with a custom object (say, Evaluation__c) and my requirement is - open a case on a VF page and display details of Evaluation__c object record below.

Am I missing something? Pls guide.

Image illustration below:
[image]

Code below:

```
            <apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                <apex:outputLabel value="Case Number" />
                <apex:inputField value="{!Evaluation__c.Case__c} " id="Case__c" label="Case Number" required="false" />
            </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>


        </apex:pageBlockSection>
        <apex:pageBlockButtons>
            <apex:commandButton value="Submit" action="{!save}" />
        </apex:pageBlockButtons>
    </apex:pageBlock>

    <apex:pageBlock>

        <apex:pageBlockSection>
            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{! Evaluation__c }" var="e">
                <apex:column value="{! e.Case__c }" />
                <apex:column value="{! e.EvaluationNumber__c }" />
                <apex:column value="{! e.Max_Points__c }" />
                <apex:column value="{! e.Score__c }" />
            </apex:pageBlockTable>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>

    </apex:pageBlock>

</apex:form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You would need a custom controller/extension which will implement search functionality. What you are doing is creating new record(while chcking submit,which is actually calling **save**) of evaluation, and thats what you see .

What you need to do is explained here.
http://gtr.net/how-to-build-a-simple-search-page-using-visualforce/

Comment: Did. Still displays nil for rest 3 fields like above image post.

Comment: It is because you are saving the Evaluation record,without this fields. CHeck the list view of evaluation, you will find plenty of Evaluation records with same case assigned.

Comment: This is particular case 1041 if you see has records exist.

Comment: Evaluation object has Lookup of Case. What you are doing is Assigning Case to Evaluation and saving it. SO new Evalution records are created without other fields being populated.